# What are the dynamic programming problems with 3D table space?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, bioinformatics

I have heard of dynamic programming problems with 2D table space (i.e., Smith Waterman). I would like to know whether there are DP problems with 3D table space. I came across 2 such problems (3D Knapsack and All-pairs shortest path), but I need to find problems with uniform dependencies i.e., (i,j,k) depends on (i+a,j+b,k+c) where a,b,c is an integer (negative or positive). For example in Smith Waterman (i,j) depends on (i-1,j), (i,j-1) and (i-1,j-1) where dependencies are uniform but 2D table space.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing stopping you from using Smith-Waterman with more than 2 dimensions.  A 3D Smith-Waterman would be the optimal alignment of 3 reads to each other.

The reason we don't often do more than 2D Smith-Waterman is the more reads you add, the search space and memory grow exponentially so it is unfeasible to use it on more than a few reads.  That's why multiple sequence alignments are often heuristic based and are not optimal.